# Se puede poner un HorizontalScrollView con Row y Key en un CustomKeyboard?

Tags: xml, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Alguien me puede ayudar si se puede integrar un **"HorizontalScrollView"** o **"ScrollView"** en los formatos/tags **"Key"** y **"Row"**, por qué tengo el problema de que no se  me trata de desplazar el Scroll dentro mi **"Keyboard"**, el siguiente código es lo que uso

Código XML:

```
<Keyboard
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="750px"
    android:verticalGap="75px">
    <Row>
                <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="42" android:keyLabel="*" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                <Key android:codes="35" android:keyLabel="#" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Ya que es la casi-primera vez que intento usar ese tipo de formato de los **"Row"**, **"Key"** y **"Keyboard"**

Y no me funciona lo siguiente
Ejemplo:

```
    <Keyboard
        android:keyWidth="10%p"
        android:horizontalGap="750px"
        android:verticalGap="75px">

        <Row>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="42" android:keyLabel="*" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                    <Key android:codes="35" android:keyLabel="#" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </Row>

    </Keyboard>
```

Y si me pueden dar un ejemplo o ayudar a cómo solucionar eso, gracias

Comment: Se te puede ayudar mostrando un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Pon además en las etiquetas a qué lenguaje estás haciendo referencia. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.